# Draw a rectangle hiding an area of a picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have something drawn as a `tikzpicture`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[above] at (8,13) {$...$};
  \filldraw[fill=white!20] (2,0) rectangle (6,12);
  \draw (2,4) -- (2,12); \draw (2,12) -- (6,12); \draw (6,12) -- (6,4);
  \draw [dashed] (6,3) -- (1,3);
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I would like to draw a non-transparent white rectangle which **hides** a part of the picture, so that what is under the rectangle becomes invisible or less visible (e.g. gray). Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: `\draw (2,4) -- (2,12); ...` is not useful after `\filldraw ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply move the `\filldraw` command to be after what you want hidden, and control the opacity with `fill opacity=<opacity>`:

[image]

If you want what is underneath to be complely hidden, adding `fill opacity=1.0` captures the specific intent (even though it is the default).

### Note:

- I changed the color to `yellow!20` to make the effect clearer in the image here. Replacing this with `fill=white` will give you the desired result.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \OpacitySetting in {1.0, 0.95, 0.75}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [blue, ultra thick] (0,2) -- (4,2);
\filldraw[fill=yellow!20, fill opacity=\OpacitySetting] (1,0) rectangle (3,4) 
    node [above left, text opacity=1.0]  {opacity=\OpacitySetting};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{0.25cm}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you... How can I do not show the edges of the rectangle?

Comment: @SoftTimur `\draw` draws just the edge of the rectangle, `\fill` just fills the rectangle without drawing the edge, while `\filldraw` does both. In other words, replace `\filldraw` with  `\fill`.